# LINQ Group By Year to Form a Tree View

Tags: c#, linq, treeview

I am trying to create a tree view that would essentially break down like so:

```
- Year
  - Month
    - Related Item
```

So we might have the Year 2022, that has several related items within the several months.

I have created the following model:

```
public class TreeYear
{
    public string NodeYear { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public List<TreeMonth> Months { get; set; }

}

public class TreeMonth
{
    public int MonthID { get; set; }
    public string MonthName { get; set; }
    public quoteSummary QuoteSummary{ get; set; }
}
```

I have written some code in my controller which currently returns every item like so:

```
  var allQuotes = QuoteSummary.ToList();

  var tree = new TreeYear();
  foreach (var quote in allQuotes)
  {
      tree.NodeYear= quote.CreatedTime.Year.ToString();
      tree.CreatedDateTime = quote.CreatedTime;
      tree.Months = new List<TreeMonth>()
      {
        new TreeMonth() {
        MonthID = quote.CreatedTime.Month,
        MonthName = getAbbreviatedName(quote.CreatedTime.Month),
        QuoteSummary = quote
        }
       };
  }
```

[image]

But obviously over here you can see that it has all 41 records of which none are grouped up by year.

I thought maybe I could write some linq something like but at the moment incorrect:

```
var groups = TheResponse.Details
             .GroupBy(
                  d => Int32.Parse(d.NodeYear),
                   (key, g) => g.GroupBy(
                       d => d.Months.Select(x => x.MonthID)),
                         (key2, g2) => g2.GroupBy(d => d.CreatedDateTime)
                        )
                    );
```

Or would I need to change the model for this idea to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then you need to flatten the inner list and then group by months again.

```
var groups = TheResponse.Details
                        .GroupBy(d => Int32.Parse(d.NodeYear))
                        .Select(d => new 
                               {
                                   Year = d.Key,
                                   MonthObj = d.SelectMany(m => m.Months)
                                               .GroupBy(m => m.MonthID)
                                               .Select(x => new 
                                                      {
                                                          MonthID = x.Key,
                                                          RelatedItem = x.ToList()
                                                      })
                               });
```

I have simplified it by using anonymous types, but you can obviously tweek it based on your resp. `Model`.

Comment: I'd say its along these lines but currently this is only returning a single year (2022) and the first month record as a child (i.e. Month id 6) as shown: https://prnt.sc/cNaCGwJbfKqw - but in reality it should also pick up 2022, 2021, 2020 - and 2022 should contain multiple months relating to that object i.e. not just month 6 but it might have a record with month 2 (feb) etc So my actual tree should be something like: https://prnt.sc/2-KXzdrir8p9

Comment: @ScuffedCoder - I am not sure if your data distribution is different. I have created some in-memory objects and the sample seems to be working fine. Check this Fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/r349gi

Comment: Ah it was indeed an error on my end - i was populating the original "response" list incorrectly. This works great - need to tweak some things a little but overall pretty close to what i needed. Thank you